# Can I start my app automatically by a update on y firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm creating an app and I need to start it by a update in my firebase realtime database.

**For example**: I updated a data in the database and in the device of an user, my app start to ring (not a notification) and open a alert on the screen with action to open the app.

It's possible?

Comment: Yes, this sounds possible.  If you actually asking *how* to do this, it's a rather broad question.

Comment: send push notification using cloud function (triggers) & use your own custom .mp3 file instead of default notification sound

Comment: It's a good Idea @SundaravelM. And Doug Stevenson, do you know how to do it?